# How to apply a variable in the url token which is of integer type using python script?

Tags: python, json

I was getting a `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` when i wanted to customise the url token where "id" is needed.

In place of one single result returned by a single id (say 303) i want to have the result for all the ids declared in the variable "station" retrieved from another url. 
the code is as follows:

```js
import urllib2
import json

#assign the url
url="http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/swd_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22operacja%22:%22stacje%22}"

# open the url 
json_obj= urllib2.urlopen(str(url))
output= json.load(json_obj) 
station_res= output ['data'] ['features']
for item in station_res:
 station= item['id']
url1="http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/meteo_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22id%22:}" +str(station)
 json_obj2= urllib2.urlopen(str(url1))
 output2= json.load(json_obj2)
 for item2 in output2 ['data']:
  print item2
```

Now that I tried to put "stations" as a string in the "url1" but it still doesn't recognise the url and returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    `File "stations.py", line 23, in <module>`
        `for item2 in output2 ['data']:`
```

`KeyError: 'data'`

Comment: Apparently, your output2 dictionary does not contain a data attribute. What's the output of `print output2` ?

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé For `print output` it returns the same error message. But normally the url works perfectly if I complete the url token with a known id value.So somehow the url is not recognised by python with the variable "station" having multiple id values form the item.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you add your `id` after '}' so your URL looks like

```
   http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/meteo_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22id%22:}331
```

when it should look like

```
 http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/meteo_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22id%22:331}
```

so I suggest :

```
url1 = 'http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/meteo_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22id%22:' + str(station) + '}'
```

and you don't need to write `str(url1)` because it is string already.

Comment: Hi @Evgeny it gives me an error of `ValueError: unsupported format character 't' (0x74) at index 65`

Comment: @SamB btw. Why do you use `%22`? You can just use `"`. Or in your case `\"`